# Plex Manager can't read files on external HD (automonted)

Tags: plex

I'm having a lot of difficulties in getting plex working. I have mapped 3 sections. 2 on my automonted external disk, 1 is on my home folder (images) which is working fine.

Problem is when I try to acces files on HDD it says that file is not available.

If I run:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/your-NTFS-partition /media/discoexterno
```

I can access it.

Don't know what to do..

Comment: The drive must be mounted for PLEX to access it. That is to be expected. I'm not seeing what the issue is.

Comment: The drive is mounted, i have dropbox folder in the same drive. And dropbox runs on boot no problems, i can access files and dropbox is syncing. Tks dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at [this article](http://keensknowledgeaccumulation.blogspot.com/2013/05/plex-media-server-not-finding-filesmedia_14.html) it would seem that you have a permissions problem. "Apparently Plex needs read and execute permission for the root directory of your media directory" -from article. Since its difficult to change permissions on an ntfs formatted drive you would want to format it to ext4 and set the permissions to 755 for the directory the movies live in.

Comment: Is there any alternative to plex ? My External Disk is shared with windows users... I guess windows can't read ext4 natively.

Comment: @user193537 - Are you trying to view the videos on your Ubuntu machine or on another machine on the network? Either way, XBMC could be an alternative. XBMC is available in the Ubuntu Software Center or as a free download for other platforms. Within XBMC, you would just need to tell it to add the folder in the external drive (or its network location, if accessing from another machine) as a source of videos.

Comment: I'm working locally, external disk is connected to my ubuntu and i can't access files via browser on my own localhost.
Sometimes i unplug the usb external drive to connect it to my brothers pc (windows).

OK @drkokandy i will take a look on XBMC thank you very much

Comment: @user193537 What is the statement in fstab that is automounting the drive?

Comment: @user193537 Yes there is an alternative, use mediatomb it's free and primarily for Linux. You can use allcast as android app to cast from mediatomb to your chromecast, PS3 or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure fstab to set the proper permissions.

There is a whole page about how to do this on the Plex site, see:
https://support.plex.tv/hc/en-us/articles/200288606-Mounting-NTFS-Drives-on-Linux

To make it short:

- Find the UUID of your drive:

  sudo blkid | grep ntfs
- create a directory where you will mount the drive:

  sudo mkdir /media/ext_NTFS_USB_Drive
- edit file  /etc/fstab with command:

  gksu gedit /etc/fstab
- add a line to this file and save.

  UUID=485CBF485CBF3014 /media/ext_NTFS_USB_Drive ntfs-3g permissions,auto 0 0

  where the UUID is the one your drive and the mount point is the folder you created.
- now mount the drive:

  sudo mount /media/ext_NTFS_USB_Drive

  (you might get an error saying the drive is already mounted, in Nautilus for example. Just unmount it - Safely Remove Drive, or click the Eject Icon in Nautilus)

Now in Plex, you need to change the location the media folder you were trying to add to somewhere inside: /media/ext_NTFS_USB_Drive